# WhatsApp end-to-end encryption

Tags: encryption, public-key, signature, keys, key-exchange

WhatsApp offers end-to-end encryption. However, when I start using it on a second device such as a PC running Windows, I can decrypt incoming messages without providing any private key into my second device or application.

When a party sends a message to my account which has two clients receiving the incoming message, on PC and mobile device, they receive the same message perfectly.

If my private key is generated by my first device and stored on my first device, how is the private key being passed to my second device without any security flaw?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72793/discussion-on-question-by-ook-whatsapp-and-line-end-to-end-encryption).

Comment: LINE has provided their [technical whitepaper](https://scdn.line-apps.com/stf/linecorp/en/csr/line-encryption-whitepaper-ver1.0.pdf) that described how message end-to-end encryption (a.k.a. Letter Sealing) was done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If by "using them on a second device such as a PC running Windows" you mean that you open Whatsapp web there, then no you cannot decrypt your messages there.

Whatsapp web is a client that connects **to your phone** (usually using whatsapp servers as proxy).

The client has shared keys with the phone (you scanned them as QR code) and the phone uses this to encrypt the already (on the phone) decrypted messages.

```
+----------------------------------+                     +----------------------------------------+
|                                  |                     |                                        |
|                                  +--------------------->                                        |
|    Whatsapp Web Client           |     encrypted       |         Whatsapp Servers               |
|                                  <---------------------+                                        |
|     shared key with phone        |                     |                                        |
+----------------------------------+                     +---+---------------------^--------------+
                                                             |                     |
                                                             |                     |
                                                             |                     |
                                                             |                     |
+-----------------------------------+                        |                     |
|         encryption secret keys    |                        |                     |
|                                   <------------------------+                     |
|                                   |                                              |
|      Your phone                   |         encrypted                            |
|                                   |                                              |
|      shared key with web client   +----------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------+
```

Basically the Web client is just a GUI for your phone client, connected (securely) over the web.

You can try the following: Turn off your phone while using whatsapp web. You will see, that you cannot send and receive messages anymore.

Comment: please share source of this descciption

Comment: I am running a program from whatsapp on my PC which can be downloaded from here https://www.whatsapp.com/download/

Comment: @RI8S I just wrote it. Source is my brain. You can look basically anywhere if you don't trust me. [e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#WhatsApp_Web)

Comment: @Ook it works the same. Turn off your phone (or use Airplane mode) and see what happens.

Comment: @Josef i have experienced it in past and your thinking seems right, but is it stated in the same way in some official document? I can find the official documents explaining how end-to-end encryption is implemented in whatsapp, but i cant find official description of how web or desktop version works

Comment: @RI8S as far as I know, there is no official documentation. You'll have to reverse engineer the protocol/application to find the details.

Comment: Whatsapp on PC doesn't receive any incoming messages when the mobile phone is on flight mode as @Josef explained, suggesting that it might work as he described here. Line, on the other hand, receives messages as normal even the phone is on flight mode.

Comment: @Josef voting up.

Comment: This leaves a question that as Whatsapp is acting as a proxy between the phone and PC client, TLS is actually used between phone and PC and Whatsapp has all the data captured if they want.

Comment: @Ook No, it's not only TLS and messages are end-to-end encrypted from phone to client. At least this was the case last time I quickly looked at that (mid 2017). Of course, Whatsapp is closed-source. There could be anything in there and even if it isn't, they can push an update to the play store tomorrow which mails all your keys to the NSA...

Comment: @Josef Got it, I missed the point. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The key factors here being that **a.** the messages are _re_-encrypted, and that **b.** the Web GUI doesn't really count as one of the "ends" (but even if it did you'd still be fine because of **a**)

Comment: is it the case that keys used to encrypt msgs between whatsapp application and webclient only reside in mobile and desktop PC and are never stored on whatsapp servers? if thats the case, where is that key is stored in the browser? Can we use web-client work over LAN without access to internet?